# Not getting output for Merge Sort

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I am trying this merge sort. But I am getting no output. Means it is giving no output on console screen even waited for 2 min. Anyone of you please help me with this. Where should I correct myself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
void MergeSort();
void Merging();

int main() {
    int arr[100];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    printf("Unsorted\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    MergeSort(arr, 0, 4);
    
    printf("Sorted\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void MergeSort(int arr[], int l, int h) {
    if (l < h) {
        int mid = (l + h) / 2;
        MergeSort(arr, l, mid);
        MergeSort(arr, mid + 1, h);
        Merging(arr, l, mid, h);
    }
}

void Merging(int arr[], int l, int mid, int h) {
    int i1 = l, i2 = mid + 1, j1 = mid, j2 = h;
    int b[6];
    int k = l;
    while (i1 <= j1 && i2 <= j2) {
        if (arr[i1] < arr[i2]) {
            b[k++] = arr[i1++];
        } else {
            b[k++] = arr[i2++];
        }
    }
    while (i1 <= j1) {
        b[k++] = arr[i1];
    }
    while (i2 <= j2) {
        b[k++] = arr[i2];
    }
    int i;
    for (i = l; i <= h; i++) {
        arr[i] = b[i];
    }
}
```

I have seen in other sites using two different arrays and first storing main array values then merging two arrays. I thought of doing it different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot about index incrementing in tail treatment in `Merging`.

[ideone](https://ideone.com/N599Zl)

```
while(i1<=j1){
    b[k++] = arr[i1++];
}
while(i2<=j2){
    b[k++] = arr[i2++];
```

Answer (score 1):

The code did not execute within time limits because it encountered itself in an infinite loop.

There are a couple of changes required:

1. The function declaration should correctly specify the number and types of the parameters.
2. For the following two `while` loops, the value of the iterators `i1` and `i2` were never changed. Therefore, it caused an infinite loop and nothing was displayed on the screen.

   ```
    while(i1<=j1){
        b[k++] = arr[i1++];
    }
    while(i2<=j2){
        b[k++] = arr[i2++];
    }
   ```

Have a look at the following corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
void MergeSort(int arr[],int l,int h);
void Merging(int arr[], int l, int mid, int h);

int main(){
    int arr[100];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    printf("Unsorted\n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    MergeSort(arr,0,4);
    
    printf("Sorted\n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
void MergeSort(int arr[],int l,int h){
    if(l<h){
        int mid = (l+h)/2;
        MergeSort(arr,l,mid);
        MergeSort(arr,mid+1,h);
        Merging(arr,l,mid,h);
    }
}
void Merging(int arr[], int l, int mid, int h){
    int i1 = l,i2 = mid+1, j1 = mid, j2 = h;
    int b[6];
    int k=l;
    while(i1<=j1&&i2<=j2){
        if(arr[i1]<arr[i2]){
            b[k++] = arr[i1++];
        }else{
            b[k++] = arr[i2++];
        }
    }
    while(i1<=j1){
        b[k++] = arr[i1++];
    }
    while(i2<=j2){
        b[k++] = arr[i2++];
    }
    int i;
    for(i=l;i<=h;i++){
        arr[i] = b[i];
    }
}
```

**Testing:**

Input: 5 4 -1 3 1

Output:

```
Unsorted
5 4 -1 3 1 
Sorted
-1 1 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to increment i1 and i2 that's why it generated an infinite loop and no output was shown on console.

```
while(i1<=j1){
        b[k++] = arr[i1++];
}
while(i2<=j2){
        b[k++] = arr[i2++];
```